# The denominator of a Bernoulli number is always **an even** integer. Why?

Tags: bernoulli-numbers

Apparently, the denominator of a Bernoulli number is always **an even** integer. Where does this come from?

Comment: What is your definition of the Bernoulli numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This follows from the [Von Staudt–Clausen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt-Clausen_theorem) which states that for even Bernoulli numbers $B_{2n}$ (odd ones are almost all 0) we have

$$
B_{{2n}}+\sum _{{(p-1)|2n}}{\frac  1p}\in \mathbb{Z }
$$

hence for $p = 2$ we have $p - 1 = 1$ which divides all $2n$ so $\frac1p$ always appears on the sum, hence the denominator of $B_{2n}$ must be divisible by 2 or else the total would not be an integer.

Maybe there is a simpler way but this theorem is a very general tool for understanding denominators of Bernoulli numbers.